# java explode a line/string like php explode

Tags: java, php

I'm making a java program that would run on a local server.

Server takes request from client using PHP .

```
   <?php

    $file = fopen('temp.txt', 'a+');
    $a=explode(':',$_GET['content']);
    fwrite($file,$a[0].':'.$a[1]. '\n');

    fclose($file); 
    ?>
```

Now I have file "temp.txt" on local server.

Java Program should open the file read line by line and each like should be divided/exploded ":" (In a line there's only one ':' )

I have tried in many ways, but could not get exactly like how PHP splits the line.

Is it possible to use same/similar explode function in JAVA.

Comment: Have you tried `String.split()`?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm

Comment: @Yogesh Suthar


Thanks dude

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, in Java you can use the [String#split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method in order to split the value of a `String` object.

**Update**:
For example:

```
String arr = "name:password";
String[] split = arr.split(":");
System.out.println("Name = " + split[0]);
System.out.println("Password = " + split[1]);
```

Comment: How to explode this one 

String arr="name:password";

Answer (score 4):

You can use [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) in Java to "explode" each line with ":".

**Edit**

Example for a single line:

```
String line = "one:two:three";
String[] words = line.split(":");
for (String word: words) {
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Output:

```
one
two
three
```

Comment: @HardProgrammer I've edited my answer to show you a basic example of line splitting. Note that the argument taken is a regular expression, so you may want to escape regex control characters (however, that's not your case here).

Comment: @Meena Vote up my question too